# Can I group * things from this data?

Tags: r

I got data with ASCII form.

I ran it with R, and these data have * marked when it is under other condition.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW0wJ.png)

V1, V2, V3, V4, V5 don't mean anything different. All that matters is to classify between *-ed things.

I tried c(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5) but it returns only the levels.

I have no idea. Help me with it.

Question. Can I specify *-ed things via some code?

Is there a way to make these columned things in one data?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Question is not clear, what is the expected output?

Comment: Oh man every time I try to deal with my curiosity, I have to learn how to express things in right form right matter...It's so...better delete my question

Comment: You want others' help for free, show at least some decent effort yourself. Help us to help you.

Comment: Sure. I usally try my best to pinpoint what I don't understand, but today was not the day. Thank you for your interest though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the values marked with *. I guess these values come with the symbol from the original file, right?

In this case use:

```
position <- grep('\\*', as.matrix(distress[]))
selectedValues <- as.matrix(distress[])[position] 
numericValues <- as.numeric(gsub('\*', '', selectedValues))
```

Comment: Oh Thank You So Much...Brilliant!